# Inaccurate Location Android

Tags: android, location, android-gps, google-location-services

Yesterday I happen to test my GPS tracking app on moving device I was being tracked well but suddenly I started getting wrong location **Exactly 282 km from actual location** Any idea why this may happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can be three main possibilities -

1. You have wifi hotspot, which was moved from one location to another. Then google have "remember" location of this access point, but point was moved.
2. Some problem with GPS driver
3. There was some bug in GPS retranslator (which is located on earth), located near your device.

Answer (score 0):

You were using getLastKnownLocation(). Acctually getLastKnownLocation start giving the last updated location of your devices. So may be this be the reason. Happen with me. As due to cloud i was not able to get Lat long so getLastKnownLocation give the address where It was updated last.

So this may be the reason...else you have to check for Log.

Comment: No, I didn't use last known location and even if I use that It will show same location not 282 Km away some random location

Comment: I don't know without looking at your code. I thought it would be happen. When I was using FusedAPi, i was new at that time so i was not updating the new location in fusedapi. So it was sending me to somewhere in Egypt and my Location was in India (nearly 4000KM). May be their will be something like this....you may be missing...!!

Comment: Didn't get  i was not updating the new location in fusedapi please explain further :)

Comment: we have to write this code...

LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);

check out this Tutorial. http://www.androidwarriors.com/2015/10/fused-location-provider-in-android.html